# how to center application on parent application in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an application that is started by a 3rd party application just running the .exe file.

Is there any way to make our application start centered over the other application?

Thanks,
Rob.

Edit: I don't have any access to the 3rd party application, so can't pass in its location or adjust its position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) to find 3party app window and then [GetWindowRect](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowRect.html) to get 3party app window position and then you can calculate where your window position should be.

Comment: That looks like what i'm after - i'll give it a try and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to locate the window of the 3rd party application. This can be done in a number of ways, depending on that app. You can P/Invke using [FindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html). This will work if the apps title if always the same or if it has a unique class name (which you can find using Spy++).

Another slightly more awkward but more powerful way is to use GetWindow/GetNextWindow to loop through all top level windows and inspect them one by one.

Once you have the hWnd of the app you call GetWindowPos or GetWindowRect to find it's location.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the **StartPostion** if you want your applciation centered of the screen.

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; in the form constructor.
```

Have a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx).

If you want your application to be center of other applciation that invoked it, you could pass that application's Loaction to your application and then it could readjust itelf by specifying its Location property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reponse. I'm not trying to Center on the Screen, I'm trying to center on an entirely different application's window. FormStartPosition.CenterParent only seems to apply to a form within the same application.

Comment: If so, then other application could pass its Location to your application.

Comment: Hi - i don't have access to the 3rd party application's code, so I can't adjust what it is passing in (i've updated my question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to center both applications. that way the 2nd one will be centered on the 1st one.

Other way is to pass the location of the 1st window to the 2nd window using command arugments,
so the 2nd application will know where to place itself once running.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't have access to modify the code for the first application, I guess I need to find out if there's a list of *all* open windows somewhere...